# Rails admin, link to /admin doesn't work with HEROKU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-admin

I'm using a HEROKU server to test my app in rails, in localhost everything is ok and my route to "localhost/admin" work ok, but when I sent my app to heroku the route to /admin doesn't work!!

My route.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  resources :seguradoras
  resources :produtos
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
   root "produtos#index"

end
```

My menu link in application.html.rb

```
<%= menu_item "Admin", rails_admin_path %>
```

my log:

```
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573449+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573451+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573453+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573455+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573456+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573458+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573463+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573460+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573461+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.574274+00:00 heroku[router]: - at=info method=GET path="/admin" host=shielded-anchorage-24735.herokuapp.com request_id=0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84 fwd="186.206.62.62" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

So can anybody help me?

---

This is my log:

```
2018-03-02T03:23:31.389525+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:31.389437 #4]  INFO -- : [fad0d297-6dac-46e6-9d46-9d9a85ddd3be] Processing by ProdutosController#index as HTML
2018-03-02T03:23:31.397192+00:00 app[web.1]: - D, [2018-03-02T03:23:31.397095 #4] DEBUG -- : [fad0d297-6dac-46e6-9d46-9d9a85ddd3be]   [1m[36mUser Load (3.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-03-02T03:23:31.398921+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:31.398840 #4]  INFO -- : [fad0d297-6dac-46e6-9d46-9d9a85ddd3be]   Rendering produtos/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-03-02T03:23:31.404409+00:00 app[web.1]: - D, [2018-03-02T03:23:31.404297 #4] DEBUG -- : [fad0d297-6dac-46e6-9d46-9d9a85ddd3be]   [1m[36mProduto Load (3.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "produtos".* FROM "produtos"[0m
2018-03-02T03:23:31.416335+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:31.416179 #4]  INFO -- : [fad0d297-6dac-46e6-9d46-9d9a85ddd3be]   Rendered produtos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.2ms)
2018-03-02T03:23:31.420714+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:31.420620 #4]  INFO -- : [fad0d297-6dac-46e6-9d46-9d9a85ddd3be] Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 19.2ms | ActiveRecord: 6.4ms)
2018-03-02T03:23:32.466172+00:00 heroku[router]: - at=info method=GET path="/seguradoras" host=shielded-anchorage-24735.herokuapp.com request_id=a03e991a-5a29-4d0f-b8a8-b9d434e19941 fwd="186.206.62.62" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=110ms status=200 bytes=6055 protocol=https
2018-03-02T03:23:32.358168+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:32.358017 #4]  INFO -- : [a03e991a-5a29-4d0f-b8a8-b9d434e19941] Started GET "/seguradoras" for 186.206.62.62 at 2018-03-02 03:23:32 +0000
2018-03-02T03:23:32.361723+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:32.361574 #4]  INFO -- : [a03e991a-5a29-4d0f-b8a8-b9d434e19941] Processing by SeguradorasController#index as HTML
2018-03-02T03:23:32.366974+00:00 app[web.1]: - D, [2018-03-02T03:23:32.366863 #4] DEBUG -- : [a03e991a-5a29-4d0f-b8a8-b9d434e19941]   [1m[36mUser Load (1.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-03-02T03:23:32.385700+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:32.385526 #4]  INFO -- : [a03e991a-5a29-4d0f-b8a8-b9d434e19941]   Rendering seguradoras/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-03-02T03:23:32.392743+00:00 app[web.1]: - D, [2018-03-02T03:23:32.392616 #4] DEBUG -- : [a03e991a-5a29-4d0f-b8a8-b9d434e19941]   [1m[36mSeguradora Load (1.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "seguradoras".* FROM "seguradoras"[0m
2018-03-02T03:23:32.460154+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:32.459990 #4]  INFO -- : [a03e991a-5a29-4d0f-b8a8-b9d434e19941]   Rendered seguradoras/index.html.erb within layouts/application (74.2ms)
2018-03-02T03:23:32.464009+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:32.463926 #4]  INFO -- : [a03e991a-5a29-4d0f-b8a8-b9d434e19941] Completed 200 OK in 102ms (Views: 84.5ms | ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)
2018-03-02T03:23:33.554036+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:33.553906 #4]  INFO -- : [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] Started GET "/admin" for 186.206.62.62 at 2018-03-02 03:23:33 +0000
2018-03-02T03:23:33.555735+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:33.555633 #4]  INFO -- : [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard as HTML
2018-03-02T03:23:33.564004+00:00 app[web.1]: - D, [2018-03-02T03:23:33.563894 #4] DEBUG -- : [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84]   [1m[36mUser Load (2.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-03-02T03:23:33.569557+00:00 app[web.1]: - I, [2018-03-02T03:23:33.569098 #4]  INFO -- : [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
2018-03-02T03:23:33.572871+00:00 app[web.1]: - F, [2018-03-02T03:23:33.572790 #4] FATAL -- : [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84]   
2018-03-02T03:23:33.572974+00:00 app[web.1]: - F, [2018-03-02T03:23:33.572904 #4] FATAL -- : [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] CanCan::AccessDenied (You are not authorized to access this page.):
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573085+00:00 app[web.1]: - F, [2018-03-02T03:23:33.573002 #4] FATAL -- : [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84]   
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573304+00:00 app[web.1]: - F, [2018-03-02T03:23:33.573154 #4] FATAL -- : [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cancancan-2.1.3/lib/cancan/ability.rb:176:in `authorize!'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573306+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.2.0/lib/rails_admin/extensions/cancancan/authorization_adapter.rb:11:in `initialize'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573308+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.2.0/lib/rails_admin/config.rb:153:in `new'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573310+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.2.0/lib/rails_admin/config.rb:153:in `block in authorize_with'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573312+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.2.0/app/controllers/rails_admin/application_controller.rb:54:in `instance_eval'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573314+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.2.0/app/controllers/rails_admin/application_controller.rb:54:in `_authorize!'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573316+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573318+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:197:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573319+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573321+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block in halting'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573323+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `block in invoke_before'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573324+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `each'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573326+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `invoke_before'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573328+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `run_callbacks'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573330+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573332+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573333+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573340+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573342+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573344+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573345+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573347+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573349+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573353+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573354+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573351+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573356+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573362+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573364+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573366+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573367+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573369+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573371+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573373+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573374+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:185:in `public_send'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573376+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:185:in `method_missing'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573378+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:17:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573380+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573382+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573388+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573390+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573392+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573393+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-pjax-1.0.0/lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573395+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/remotipart-1.3.1/lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573397+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573398+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573400+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573402+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573404+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573405+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573407+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573409+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573411+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573412+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573414+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573416+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573424+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573417+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573431+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573426+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573433+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573435+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573437+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573438+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573440+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573442+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573444+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573446+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573448+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573449+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573451+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573453+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573455+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573456+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573458+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573463+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573460+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.573461+00:00 app[web.1]: - [0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
2018-03-02T03:23:33.574274+00:00 heroku[router]: - at=info method=GET path="/admin" host=shielded-anchorage-24735.herokuapp.com request_id=0192d3ad-c0f5-456f-a545-db35048c4a84 fwd="186.206.62.62" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

Comment: Add the full log, please

Comment: Do you have https configured on heroku?

Comment: It is better to update your question, not add an answer with updates

Comment: `Completed 401 Unauthorized ...
CanCan::AccessDenied (You are not authorized to access this page.)` - it is from your logs. So you have some troubles with CanCanCan-RailsAdmin integration. What is in `ability.rb`?

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to add some `admin` attribute to the user on heroku?